# Unity Showing image in 3D space with maintaining aspect ratio

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to download and show an image in 3D space (and not in canvas) maintaining aspect ratio.
For this purpose, I created a Plane and set the image as its texture. The image is visible fine except that the image is squeezed to fit into the panel area.

Is there a way to make sure that the image is visible maintaining its aspect ratio and not squeezed?

Thanks,
Akshay Shah.

Answer (score 1):

```
var w= texture2D.width;
var h= texture2D.height;
plane.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1.0f, (float) h / w, 1.0f);
```

Comment: Didn't really try this but did you test it to to see if it works?